# How can I implement CALL intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

This is what I am doing now. I am getting the following error

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=16477210790 }

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(store_contact_no.getText().toString()));
        startActivity(callIntent);

    }
```

Comment: did you provided the necessary permission?

Comment: Did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`? If yes, did you try catching this exception and using `ACTION_DIAL` instead?

Comment: permission is added already.And I need the ACTION_CALL not ACTION_DIAL

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare dial intent-filter in manifest and don't need any permissions to ACTION_DIAL. Look for my implementation

```
private void startDialActivity(String phone){
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));
startActivity(intent);}
```

also is good to check is telephony supported on device

```
private boolean isTelephonyEnabled(){
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
return tm != null && tm.getSimState()==TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY;}
```

use this code.
this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

In Activity check permission,

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 1);
        }
    } else {
        Call(sNumber);
    }
```

where sNumber is your number in string

then Override onRequestPermissionsResult,

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 100:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted,
                Call(sNumber);

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {

                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 1);

                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

add this method,

```
 private void Call(String sNumber)
{
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + sNumber));
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```